# SQL Delete with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL command that will delete all rows with a 0 as the last digit in a column, then a 1 as the last digit, a 2 as the last digit, and so on.

```
delete from BASE_TABLE where SET = 'ABCD'
```

This statement would delete 400,000+ rows at once and my service can't handle this.

**to break it up I wanted to to say something like**

```
delete from BASE_TABLE
where BASE_TABLE.SET = 'ABCD'
and BASE_TABLE.TAG LIKE '%0'
```

After I delete everything with LIKE `'%0'` I would want to delete everything with LIKE `'%1'`, all the way through LIKE `'%9'`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in a `while` loop.  However,  more typical approach would be:

```
delete top 10 percent from BASE_TABLE
where BASE_TABLE.SET = 'ABCD';
```

Or, just a fixed number that you can handle:

```
delete top 1000 from BASE_TABLE
where BASE_TABLE.SET = 'ABCD';
```

You can then put this in a loop:

```
declare @x int;
set @x = 1;

while @x > 0 begin
    delete top 1000 from BASE_TABLE
    where BASE_TABLE.SET = 'ABCD';

    set @x = @@ROWCOUNT;
end;
```

Don't put the `percent` method in the `while` loop.  It will keep going for a long time -- because the percent is based on the rows in the table at the time.  I believe it will eventually delete the last row, but there will be a lot of iterations.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. I'm going to try something like this and see if it works for me. I'll post back here and select the correct answer soon. I am sure that BASE_TABLE.TAG is always numerical, do you think I should still account for this?

Comment: @Larnu . . . That condition is not in the original `delete` statement.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the second statement, maybe I should edit the post for clarity. The second statement was just an example of how I was thinking to solve the problem

Comment: If I went with the `top 10 percent` approach, would all the records eventually be deleted? or 10% at a time until 100% of the rows are deleted? Trying to wrap my head around that one

Comment: @Josh . . . That version shouldn't go in a loop . . . this is related to Zero's paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Correct, I meant the first statement you provided, `delete top 10 percent from BASE_TABLE
where BASE_TABLE.SET = 'ABCD';`

Answer (score 1):

If system load is all you care about, just delete the top X rows. Here's the syntax

```
DELETE TOP (top_value) [ PERCENT ] 
FROM table
[WHERE conditions];
```

You could apply an order by if you want to delete in a certain order. If you want the process to do all the work for you, stick it in a loop until the table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need `[0-9]%` in `where clause`

This will delete all the rows begining with `0 to 9` and if you want ending with shift the `%` to the left as 
`%[0-9]`

Comment: Will this iterate over those numbers or delete anything with a last digit between 0-9?

Comment: Obviously, it has to iterate so as to delete those rows one by one but this is implicit

Comment: I meant will this delete all with 0, then 1, then 2, etc? It isn't so obvious to me hence why I'm here asking the question lol

Comment: read my answer carefully first and don't you think how you perform `select` data via like `%..` its the same way it will delete as well provided the column you mentioned is valid.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what I want it to do, I would like it to delete rows with 0-9 in seemingly separate SQL statements. Delete all the 0,s then deletes all the  1's, until all the rows are in a looping style